# Live changes in a hidden inputfield sent to a JavaScript Variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, hidden

I am trying to read a hidden element on the run as it is being changed by a JavaScript slidebar (Tigra Slider Control) and put the stored number into a JavaScript variable.

However:

-I have read somewhere that the onchange:"" function is rendered null, because it doesn't trigger when the field is manipulated through means other then the user.

-I'm trying to avoid having to press a button to set the reading in motion, the idea is that the image that is connected to the number changes as the user slides the bar around.

If anyone could help me out with this, I'd be grateful.

-~Rik

Answer (score 1):

There is no event that covers this scenario, so the only real way to do it is to poll the value of the input element.

I would not advice you to do this, since it is a poor implementation, the better way to solve the problem is to either

1. change the source code of the slider control to allow for a callback function to be triggered when the slider has changed position
2. use another slider control that already implements this functionality - there should be plenty to choose from with a little googeling

Should you still wish to implement it by polling the value of the input field it can be done like so:

```
<script>
  var hiddenInputElement = document.getElementById('*insert id of input field*'),
      hiddenInputElementPreviousValue;
  setInterval(function(){
    if(hiddenInputElementPreviousValue != hiddenInputElement.value) {
      hiddenInputElementPreviousValue = hiddenInputElement.value;
      /* value has changed, act on it */
    }
  }, 100);
</script>
```

You can of course change the interval to something other than 100ms - whatever suits your needs

Comment: Perfect answer - I just took a peek at this slider control and yeah... You can do better.